# unicode characters in a Smalltalk FFI call to OpenDBX

Tags: unicode, smalltalk, squeak, pharo, ffi

I need to insert some strings containing non ASCII characters into the database (Postgress). Here is the minimal example. I get the "Could not coerce arguments" on `<cdecl: long 'odbx_query' (ulong char* ulong) module: 'opendbx'>`. From what I understand it is a FFI error and the call didn't even make it to the database backend, but I'm not sure.

```
| conn settings sql |
settings :=     DBXConnectionSettings
                host: 'host.com'
                port: '5432'
                database: 'grss'
                userName: 'username'
                userPassword: 'password'.
conn := DBXConnection platform: DBXPostgresPlatform new settings: settings.
conn connectAndOpen.
sql := 'select ''', (WideString fromPacked: 269), ''' from dual'.
conn execute: sql.
conn close.
conn disconnect.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I had the same problem. One should encode data using same encoding than the server. Currently you should be able to specify encoding in following way:

```
settings :=     DBXConnectionSettings
                host: 'host.com'
                port: '5432'
                database: 'grss'
                userName: 'username'
                userPassword: 'password';
                encodingStrategy: (DBXStaticEncoding newForEncoding: #utf8).
```

If encoding is not known one could use `DBXAutomaticEncoding` instead of `DBXStaticEncoding`.
This should work on postgresql database.

Comment: Um encodingStrategy, DBXStaticEncoding... honestly did you make those up? I don't have those in my image.

Comment: GlorpDBX 1.3 contains it. Can be found on `OpenDBX-Core-MarianoMartinezPeck.271`.

Comment: Fair enough. But I'm not using GLORP. Just plain DBX.

Comment: It might be a good thing to someday merge those encoding changes to plain DBX too..

Answer (score 1):

THe problem seems to be the WideString. It seems that FFI cannot convert from WideString instances to C  char*

Can you use normal ByteString instead of the wide?   maybe FFI could be fixed so that it can do it?

Comment: ByteString does not fit most of the world. I found a workaround. Luckily, postgres can interpret escaped unicode. For example &U'\010D' is char 269.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how to answer to someone here in stackoverflow. Anyway, what Panu says should work:

```
settings :=     DBXConnectionSettings
                host: 'host.com'
                port: '5432'
                database: 'grss'
                userName: 'username'
                userPassword: 'password';
                encodingStrategy: (DBXStaticEncoding newForEncoding: #utf8).
```

without needing to needing to direclty use UTF8TextConverter. That's the way to do it with SqueakDBX. And it has nothing to do with GlorpDBX, it is just plain SqueakDBX. If the latest ConfigurationOfSqueakDBX is not updated, just update to the latest versions using Monticello Browser.

Comment: Updating using Monticello did the trick. I was using `(ConfigurationOfSqueakDBX project version: '1.2') load` previously, but that wasn't new enough apparently.

Answer (score 0):

FFI's char* wants a ByteString. Maybe postgres can use UTF-8 directly? If so, you just would have to say squeakToUtf8.

Comment: No object understands squeakToUtf8 :/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using

`UTF8TextConverter >> convertToSystemString`

and

`UTF8TextConverter >> convertFromSystemString`